# I have a image that comes from backend, and I have drawn boxes over that image, but i'm unable to draw them on specific points that I want

Tags: vue.js

I need to scale the image to my containers width and height to properly place these specific points but I'm unable to do so.

Here is my code.

```
                    <div class="img-magnifier-container" @click = "drawboxes">
                      <b-img 
                        style= "position:relative"                      
                        :id="'og'+(i+1)"
                        :src="pageImage.pageValue"
                        class="page-image"
                      >                      
                      </b-img>
                      <div class = "expo" style="position:absolute; left:155.76px; top:152.89px; height:2.2%; width:30.2%; border: 2px solid red;"/>
                    </div>
```

Here I have given static div just to test. I thought I can take the natural height and width and divide that by my container height and width to get the ratio. It doesnt seem to work though. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting the image height and width to 100% in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
img style="width:100%;height:100%"
```

Or in css it scales to parent div perfectly.